# MS Graph - Restrict access on API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We need to get information of one channel in MS Teams so I created a app with API permission **ChannelMessage.Read.All** rights. Is it possible to restrict access for this application to one or two MS Teams channels only ?

Create API with following rights : **ChannelMessage.Read.All**

Comment: This scenario is currently not supported. If you are using Delegated 
ChannelMessage.Read.All permissions, it allows an app to read a channel's messages in Microsoft Teams, on behalf of the signed-in user.

If you are using Application ChannelMessage.Read.All permissions, it allows the app to read all channel messages in Microsoft Teams, without a signed-in user.

Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

Comment: thank you for your reply, do you know if there is another way to get all information / message for a channel/teams ?

Comment: You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to retrieve the list of messages (without the replies) in a channel of a team. You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to retrieve the properties and relationships of a channel. However please note that once you grant a permission you cannot restrict to just one or two channels.